# Call Ajax on href click

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a series of links which I want to call using Ajax

```
<a href="AddElement.php?Type=Example">Link</a>
<a href="AddElement.php?Type=ExampleTwo">Link</a>
<a href="AddElement.php?Type=ExampleThree">Link</a>
```

I have tried the below to no avail:

```
<a id="data" href="#" data-href="Example">

<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).on('click','#data',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var data = $(this).data('href');
        $.ajax({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'AddElement.php?Type=',
            data: data,
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data){
            alert('Success');  
            }
        });
    });      
</script>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: How do the first 3 links relate to the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define custom attributes and use those in the script as below.

```
data-url="AddElement.php?Type=" href="#" data-value="Example"
```

```js
$(document).on('click','#data',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var URL = $(this).data('url');
        var data = $(this).data('value');
        $.ajax({
            method: 'get',
            url: URL,
            data: data,
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data){
              alert('Success');  
            },
            error: function (data) {
              console.log('Error');  
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a a id="data" data-url="AddElement.php?Type=" href="#" data-value="Example">Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `data-href` value in the `url` option, not in the `data` option. Therefore it should be

```
var hrefVal = $(this).data('href');
$.ajax({
   method: 'get',
   url: 'AddElement.php?Type=' + hrefVal,
   async: true,
   cache: false,
   success: function (data){
      alert('Success');  
   }
});
```

Comment: This works for the first link, but not for the others?